# IncludePHP plugin's not working in joomla 1.5

Tags: plugins, joomla1.5

I have a website created in joomla and i used incudePHP plugin to add html pages to content. It used to work perfectly for a long while.. but now i don't know why it shows the code :
    {htmlfile}tours/rafting.html{/htmlfile}     instead of the content that that file has. It seems perfectly fine and still it doesn't work! It's frustrating :(

Any idea what could have gone wrong?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that's interested in this issue..here's what i did:
Apparently it was the plugin's fault! It just didn't work anymore, so i took 'DirectPHP plugin' instead and it worked like charm! I just needed to add this code to all my links:
    "      " 
..and the content showed just fine! :)

Cheers